# Titanium appcelarator Data exceeds UNCOMPRESS_DATA_MAX (3964928 vs 1048576) in Android 2.2

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator-mobile, android-2.2-froyo

We are using Titanium to develop Android applications. We have a database close to 4 MB size and gets the error

> "D/asset   (  310): Data exceeds UNCOMPRESS_DATA_MAX (3964928 vs 1048576)"

when running in emulator. I learned that it is because android supports only 1MB as maximum file size in 2.2.

How can we fix this for 2.2 using Titanium?

Comment: I renamed .sqllite to .png as it png is already compressed or not required to be compressed and it works. But is it the best solution?

http://www.nutprof.com/2010/12/data-exceeds-uncompressdatamax.html

Answer (score 1):

this is not an appcelerator issue it is just a constraint of the underlying technology, Android.

I ran into this problem before and implemented a similar renaming workaround as you have.

Answer (score 0):

I did the same thing once before, but I found that another solution is to simply download the database from an internet location to the apps private storage. That way you don't have to hassle with copying a database nor does your app double in size when it copies it from your assests.

Of course, not everyone is able to host a file like that, so in that case you are just going to have to stick with the rename workaround.

Comment: During this development the database is now 25 MB and is expecting to grow even more. I don't think it will be a good idea for users to download with in the application. U paid/downloaded the app, it is then downloading something with in doesn't make logical. Any other work arounds ...?